# Changing WPF border visibility after opening dialog box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a border control that I am using as a loading screen overlay over my main window for when I am opening a couple large files. To do this, I am changing the visibility property of the border to Visible after the dialog box is created. The problem is that the border never actually shows up. This is the code that does not work:

```
  var openFileDialog = new ViewerOpenFileDialog();
  openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
  LoadingScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  ViewerViewModel.OpenFile(openFileDialog.ParamFileName, openFileDialog.IdFileName);
  LoadingScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

After I close the dialog, the border never becomes visible.

This code DOES work, however:

```
   LoadingScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   var openFileDialog = new ViewerOpenFileDialog();
   openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
   ViewerViewModel.OpenFile(openFileDialog.ParamFileName, openFileDialog.IdFileName);
   LoadingScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

The border becomes visible until after my files load, however it is visible while my dialog box is open which is not ideal.

Here is the XAML for my border:

```
    <Border Name="LoadingScreen" Background="#80000000" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Loading, Please Wait..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

Comment: Why not just customize a busy indicator's style template?

Comment: Have you tried starting a new thread that opens the file and sets the loading screen visibility to hidden?  That should give the UI Thread time to make the loading screen visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that, if you close the Dialog, your WPF Form needs to render the Controls,
because the OpenFileDialog covers parts of your WPF window.
If you set the visibility from CodeBehind you need to tell your window, that it has to
render this area again.

So you might try to call:

`LoadingScreen.Invalidate(true);`

after setting the visibility in your first example.

---

Since you use WPF there might be a better Solution.

Expecting your first example is in the ViewModel of your window you could just add
a Property with a BackingField and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (and of course set the DataContext):

```
private Visibility _loadScreenVisibility;

public Visibility LoadScreenVisibility
{
    get { return _loadScreenVisibility; }
    set
    {
        _loadScreenVisibility = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("LoadScreenVisibility");
    }
}
```

In your XAML you can then use

```
<Border Visibility="{Binding Path=LoadScreenVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... >
    <... />
</Border>
```

Comment: I fixed it by using your suggestion to set it in the ViewModel and putting the file reading in a separate thread. Thanks.